Python Selenium ChromeDriver send_keys for forward slash (/) is not working on Linux
Python Selenium ChromeDriver send_keys for forward slash (/) is not working on Linux. However it is working perfectly on Windows PC. The below is my code snipet.
msg_q = '12/04/1983'
msgBox_xpath = '//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/p'
msgBox = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, msgBox_xpath)))
time.sleep(2)
msgBox.click()
time.sleep(2)
msgBox.send_keys(msg_q)
time.sleep(2)
msgBox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

When run it typed as 12041983 instead of 12/04/1983. The forward slashes are skipped. Any help? I am unable to fix the issue.
I have tried different chromedriver but the issue is not fixed. I want to type 12/04/1981 not 12041983

That's probably not your exact code, so are you quite sure you didn't make a forward/backward slash mistake?  Where did msg_q come from?

msg_q value come from mySQL table as date. But I have assigned the value of msg_q = '12/04/1983' exclusively. Still not works.

Your XPATH points to a <p>, not to an <input> tag.  Are you sure that tag accepts input?  The slash character does have a special purpose in Chrome when focus is not within an <input> tag.

Yes. I am sure to <p> tag on click it appears hidden <input>. Just similar to WhatsApp Web UI. Moreover the same code is working on Windows PC perfectly. But the issue on Linux VPS (Debiun). All other inputs with special character like ? ( { [ #etc. are working.

If there is a hidden <input>, then you need to send the keystrokes to that <input> tag.

The way send_keys works is it doesn't enter the character from the string but the key binded to that character based on the machine setup that we are running our tests on. So in my cause I had to simulate pressing / and ALT at the same time.
textbox.send_keys("/") # "/" => shift back to the beginning
textbox.send_keys(Keys.ALT, "/") # "/" => "/"

